# Extract only numbers

Tags: regex, tableau-api

I am trying to write a regular expression that matches a number which is between parentheses.

Sample input lines:

```
Resolution(03:03): the software is installed
Resolution(10:12): software removed
Resolution(05:01): Software configuration
```

I want to match:

```
03:03
10:12
05:01
```

Numbers have different values. eg,

01:01 - 01:99
   01:01 - 99:01
   99:01 - 99:99

The message part contains only one text, eg:

Message cancel by the user

How can I search this text using "contains" function?

Comment: try :- `REGEXP_EXTRACT([Field Name], '\(([^)]*)\)')`

Answer (score 1):

- `(\d{2}:\d{2})` - Your regexp
- `\((\d{2}:\d{2})\)` - or this one
- `Resolution\((\d{2}:\d{2})\)` - or maybe with "Resolution" keyword?

[Website you should read if want use REGEXP like a PRO](http://www.regular-expressions.info/)

Answer (score 1):

To match only the numbers, use look behind/ahead assertions:

```
(?<=\()\d\d:\d\d(?=\))
```

Look arounds assert without capturing, so the entire match is just the numbers part. The brackets are asserted, but not part of the match.